# HTML/CSS mouse hover property does not cover the form texts

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am currently developing a project in jsp. I have designed the menu with submenus which on mouse hover shows the dropdown sub menus. The problem arises when I hover the mouse over the menu, it covers the form but I want it to be on top on mouse hover. The form text should not come on the menu. Please someone help me.

This is my screnshot Link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0UDalBYIopamdTM1F0RGVqYlk/view

Comment: Please use the insert picture feature to the editor to include images, rather than a link to some third party site. Also, please include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I achieved it with the help of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue of [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) your menu e.g. with `position: relative;` and set your z-index e.g. to `z-index: 10;` - it has to be a value greater than the one from your form. If you haven't set a `z-index` on your form, its initial value is `auto`, so a value greater than 1 should bring your hover menu to the front.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to SO ;) I would appreciate an accept ;)